# How can I check if one of two inputs checked, then disable the other one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write a jQuery code to check if one of the two inputs is checked, then disable the other one.

Here is my code but it does not work properly. Hope someone checks it and let me what should I do.

```js
if ($("[name='input_6_8']").val()) {
  $("[name='input_6_9']").prop("disabled", "disabled"), $("[name='input_6_9']").addClass('greyed');
} else {
  $("[name='input_6_9']").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled"), $("[name='input_6_9']").removeClass('greyed');
}

if ($("[name='input_6_9']").val()) {
  $("[name='input_6_8']").prop("disabled", "disabled"), $("[name='input_6_8']").addClass('greyed');
} else {
  $("[name='input_6_8']").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled"), $("[name='input_6_8']").removeClass('greyed');
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion_section {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 32px 5%;
}

.accordion {
  background-color: rgb(229, 246, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: rgb(17, 146, 232);
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.accordion__content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 80%;
}

.accordion__content--text {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
  text-align: right;
}

.accordion__content--input input {
  background: rgb(229, 246, 255);
  border: 0px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  outline: none;
  color: rgb(135, 141, 150);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.accordion__content--input input::placeholder {
  color: rgb(135, 141, 150);
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: rgb(229 246 255 / 69%);
}

.panel {
  padding: 0px 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="accordion__main">
    <button class="accordion">My lowest test grade is dropped. What do I need to get?</button>
    <div class="panel six">
      <div class="panel_content six_8">
        <div class="accordion__content">
          <div class="accordion__content--text">
            How many tests does your final worth?
          </div>
          <div class="accordion__content--input">
            <input name="input_6_8" type="number" placeholder="e.g. 0 tests">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel_content six_9">
        <div class="accordion__content">
          <div class="accordion__content--text">
            How much does your final worth?
          </div>
          <div class="accordion__content--input">
            <input name="input_6_9" type="number" placeholder="e.g. 10 %">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You mean you want to disable one input when someone enter anything in another input, right ?

Comment: Number inputs can't be "checked". Please revise to be more clear, and remove anything not relevant to your actual question. The accordion and all that CSS are just distractions.

Answer (score 1):

You can get click event for 2 elements at once with the selector by addind "," between elements.

Then to know wich element is clicked, you need to get the value of name attribute.

Finally, you just need to check wich one is click and then disabled it.

```js
$("[name='input_6_8'], [name='input_6_9']").on('input', function() {
  // first we enable 2 inputs at once
  $("[name='input_6_8'], [name='input_6_9']").removeAttr( "disabled", "disabled" );

  // get name attribute of clicked element
  var getName = $(this).attr('name');
  var getVal = $(this).val();

  // we check if val of click element is empty
  if (getVal != '') {
    if (getName == "input_6_8") {
      $("[name='input_6_9']").prop( "disabled", "disabled" ).toggleClass('greyed');
    } else if (getName == "input_6_9") {
      $("[name='input_6_8']").prop( "disabled", "disabled" ).toggleClass('greyed');
    }
  }
});

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion_section {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 32px 5%;
}

.accordion {
    background-color: rgb(229, 246, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: rgb(17, 146, 232);
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-family: inherit;
}

.accordion__content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 80%;
}

.accordion__content--text {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    text-align: right;
}

.accordion__content--input input {
    background: rgb(229, 246, 255);
    border: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    outline: none;
    color: rgb(135, 141, 150);
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.accordion__content--input input::placeholder {
    color: rgb(135, 141, 150);
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {background-color: rgb(229 246 255 / 69%);}

.panel {
    padding: 0px 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="accordion__main">
         <button class="accordion">My lowest test grade is dropped. What do I need to get?</button>
         <div class="panel six">
            <div class="panel_content six_8">
               <div class="accordion__content">
                  <div class="accordion__content--text">
                     How many tests does your final worth?                           
                  </div>
                  <div class="accordion__content--input">
                     <input name="input_6_8" type="number" placeholder="e.g. 0 tests">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel_content six_9">
               <div class="accordion__content">
                  <div class="accordion__content--text">
                     How much does your final worth?                           
                  </div>
                  <div class="accordion__content--input">
                     <input name="input_6_9" type="number" placeholder="e.g. 10 %">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```